# Binary search giving TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, binary-search

I am trying to perform a binary search. I keep running into an error:

```
    outcome = overlap (base, start_pos, end_pos)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The error can be found on line 58 of this code. I have marked it out in the code.

```
def overlap (x, start_y, end_y):
    if x < start_y:
        return -2
    elif x > end_y:
        return 2
    elif x >= start_y and x <= end_y:
        return 0

import csv

file1 = open ('path_to_file','rt', newline = '')
bait = csv.reader(file1, delimiter = '\t')

file2 = open ('path_to_file','rt', newline = '')
stress_33 = csv.reader(file2, delimiter = '\t')

file3 = open ('path_to_file','wt', newline ='')
output = csv.writer(file3, delimiter = '\t')

file4 = open ('path_to_file','wt', newline ='')
output_off = csv.writer(file4, delimiter = '\t')

files = file1, file2, file3, file4

bait_dict = {}

for line in bait:
    chromosome = line[0]
    start = int(line[1])
    end = int(line[2])
    location = start, end
    if chromosome not in bait_dict:
        bait_dict[chromosome] = []
        bait_dict[chromosome].append (location)
    elif chromosome in bait_dict:
        bait_dict[chromosome].append (location)

for item in bait_dict:
    bait_dict[item].sort(key = lambda i: i[0])

no_overlap = 0
overlap = 0

for i, line in enumerate(stress_33):
    if i == 0:
        output.writerow(line)
        output_off.writerow(line)
    elif i > 0:
        chrom_stress = line[1]
        base = int(line[2])
        if chrom_stress in bait_dict:
            for key, value in bait_dict.items():
                low = 0
                high = len(value) -1
                while low <= high:
                    mid = (low + high)//2
                    start_pos, end_pos = value[mid]
                    outcome = overlap (base, start_pos, end_pos) # TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
                    if outcome == 0:
                        output.writerow(line)
                    else:
                        if outcome == -2:
                            low = mid + 1
                        elif outcome == 2:
                            high = mid - 1
                no_overlap += 1
                output_off.writerow(line)    

print ('Number of ontarget is %d an number of off target is %d' %(overlap, no_overlap))


for file in files:
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to call `overlap` as a function, when you have declared it as an integer. I'm not sure what you're trying to do on line 58, so it's hard to suggest how to fix it, but the reason is that `overlap` is simply not a function.

EDIT: Oh, I didn't see that you had declared a function called `overlap` earlier. The reason you get the error is that after declaring the function, you redeclare `overlap` as an integer. Simply choose a different name for the function or the value and you should be golden.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have both a variable `overlap` and a function named `overlap`. In Python, functions and values are all objects living in the same namespace.

Your function at the top is called `overlap`, and further down you *rebind* the name to contain an integer:

```
overlap = 0
```

Now your function object is no longer addressable (it has been cleaned up, it no longer exists past that point).

Rename either the function or the variable.

Comment: Thanks guys. Great catch! I really appreciate you spotting the mistake. I went through the code a couple of times looking our for an error like that but I could not find it. I guess it happens when you have stared at a code for too long.